# Budgie lockscreen persists after attempting to reinstall gdm3

Tags: uninstall, 20.04, lock-screen, budgie

I switched from the new gnome DE to Budgie, but when I switched back I realized that the Budgie lockscreen was still in place. Here are the commands I used to attempt the switch:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-budgie-desktop ubuntu-budgie* lightdm
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3
```

Here is an image of their output:

[terminal commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IknTj.jpg)

Comment: perhaps a reboot could fix this issue?

Comment: I reboot, twice but it didn`t worked.

Comment: this is just a shot in the dark, but could you try the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` instead?

Comment: I'm glad that worked. If you want to resolve this question, put what you said in the answer box and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I typed these commands: `sudo apt-get install gdm3` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`.